# AppCompatButton not changing Text nor background with selectors

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a button that I have defined two selectors one for the text and one for background.

### Selector for text color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/yellow" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/pink" android:state_activated="false" />
</selector>
```

### Selector for background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_no_selected" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_selected" android:state_activated="false" />
</selector>
```

### Button in Xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            ....
            android:background="@drawable/selector_background"
            ...
            android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_color"
            />
```

When I press the button I want to change the state so I put this :

```
myButton.isSelected = isSelected //boolean that changes true or false
```

But is not changing the button even-though I'm changing the `isSelected` what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Selected isn't the same as activated. You need to use either:

- `myButton.isActivated = ...`
- Or change `android:state_activated` to `android:state_selected`:

  ```xml
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_no_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_selected" android:state_selected="false" />
  </selector>
  ```

  (it seems like your drawable names or reversed here by the way)

Comment: Any idea @Nicolas?

Comment: Did you try both solutions?

Comment: Yes both and not working, I have `state_activate` and when clicking the button I'm adding `myButton.isActivated=true` but not changing anything

Comment: It's not entirely impossible that the button doesn't handle the `activated` drawable state. Try using `isSelected` and changing the XML selector state attribute to `android:state_selected`. Or did you try that already?